# Please suggest the best approach for initializing variable with default values while creating object & manipulating value of same variable later on

Tags: java

Req:I have a class containing 10 variables & while creating an object of that class,I want the object to be initialized with default values & later on the those variable present in the object are manipulated with new values based on conditional check

Currently I am using package scope while creating variables and also constructor to initialize instance variables with default values and accessing the instance variables from some other class as the scope is package.

```
package com.test;
import java.util.List;
public class NodeListInputDetails  
{
     int inputRequest;   // tells what fields to read from XML request
     int level; 
     List<String> idList;
     //interested levels

     int langId;
     boolean checkViews;
     int views;
     boolean returnCounts;
     long minCount;
     boolean returnAttributes;
     boolean returnVisitValues;
     String navAreaFilter;
     boolean isDefaultText;
     boolean forceAlphabeticalSorting;
     boolean retainAncestorsOnly;


     NodeListInputDetails(int inputRequest, int level, int langId, int views,  long minCount, boolean checkViews, boolean returnCounts, boolean returnAttributes, boolean returnVisitValues, String navAreaFilter, boolean isDefaultText, boolean forceAlphabeticalSorting, boolean retainAncestorsOnly)
     {
        this.inputRequest=inputRequest;
        this.level=level;
        this.langId=langId;
        this.views=views;
        this.minCount=minCount;
        this.checkViews=checkViews;
        this.returnCounts=returnCounts;
        this.returnAttributes=returnAttributes;
        this.returnVisitValues=returnVisitValues;
        this.navAreaFilter=navAreaFilter;
        this.isDefaultText=isDefaultText;
        this.forceAlphabeticalSorting=forceAlphabeticalSorting;
        this.retainAncestorsOnly=retainAncestorsOnly;
    }
    public int getInputRequest()
    {
        return inputRequest;
    }
    public int getLevel()
    {
        return level;
    }
    public int getLangId()
    {
        return langId;
    }
    public boolean getCheckViews()
    {
        return checkViews;
    }
    public int getViews()
    {
        return views;
    }
    public boolean getReturnCounts()
    {
        return returnCounts;
    }
    public long getMinCount()
    {
        return minCount;
    }
    public boolean getReturnAttributes()
    {
        return returnAttributes;
    }
    public boolean getReturnVisitValues()
    {
        return returnVisitValues;
    }
    public String getNavAreaFilter()
    {
        return navAreaFilter;
    }
    public boolean getIsDefaultText()
    {
        return isDefaultText;
    }
    public boolean getForceAlphabeticalSorting()
    {
        return forceAlphabeticalSorting;
    }
    public boolean getRetainAncestorsOnly()
    {
        return retainAncestorsOnly;
    }
}

package com.test;
class Test
{
    int INCLUDE_ALL_LEVELS=-1;
    String navAreaFilter="";
    NodeListInputDetails input=new NodeListInputDetails(0x001,     INCLUDE_ALL_LEVELS,0,0,0,false,false,true,false,navAreaFilter,false,false,false);
    input.inputRequest=10;
}
```

Comment: Limit the number of arguments in the constructor. This is not a minimal example.

Answer (score -1):

There are syntax errors. Try the below code, this should fix your issue. Best practice would be to use a method to do object initializations.

```
class Test {
    int INCLUDE_ALL_LEVELS=-1;
    String navAreaFilter="";
    NodeListInputDetails input= null;
    public void init() {
        input = new NodeListInputDetails(0x001,     INCLUDE_ALL_LEVELS,0,0,0,false,false,true,false,navAreaFilter,false,false,false);
        input.inputRequest=10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.init();
    }}
```

Comment: Also always set `private` modifier to instance variables and modify its value using getter\setter methods.

Comment: A best practice comment

Comment: So can i use constructor and also setter both for satisfying the requirement? Is it fine to use that way?